AWS EKS : Creating a statefulset. Each replica with it's own persistent storage on EFS
I'm trying to deploy a statefulset with 3 replicas on AWS EKS, with each replica having it's own persistent storage(on efs) dynamically created.
The efs server address is stored in aws secrets manager.
But it's not working.
I'm getting the following error:
Warning FailedScheduling 4m58s default-scheduler 0/1 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
Any help is appreciated.
secrets-provider-class.yaml
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: aws-secrets-provider
spec:
  provider: aws
  parameters:
    objects:  |
      - objectName: "efs-server-address"
        objectType: secretsmanager
        objectVersion: ""

efs-storageclass.yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: efs-storageclass
provisioner: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
parameters:
  secretProviderClass: "aws-secrets-provider"

eks-secrets-manager-efs-sa.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: eks-secrets-manager-efs-sa
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:policy/eks-secrets-manager-efs-policy

efs-pvc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-storageclass
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        fileSystemId: fs-0f012ab34567ab89c

statefulset-01.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: statefulset-01
  labels:
    app: app-sample-01
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-sample-01
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-sample-01
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: eks-secrets-manager-efs-sa
      containers:
        - name: container-sample-01
          image: '123456789000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sample-repo:latest'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: efs-volume
              mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
      - metadata:
          name: efs-volume
        spec:
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteMany
          storageClassName: efs-storageclass
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 1Gi


I recommend you use the AWS EFS CSI driver.
Then you can use dynamic provisioning so that each pod gets a separate subpath in the same EFS filesystem (you don't need a separate EFS filesystem for each pod).  Check the subPathPattern option in the StorageClass here:
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
  fileSystemId: fs-92107410
  directoryPerms: "700"
  gidRangeStart: "1000" # optional
  gidRangeEnd: "2000" # optional
  basePath: "/dynamic_provisioning" # optional
  subPathPattern: "${.PVC.namespace}/${.PVC.name}" # optional
  ensureUniqueDirectory: "true" # optional
  reuseAccessPoint: "false" # optional

Alternatively, you can use a AWS EBS CSI driver which will provision a separate volume for each pod and typically will give you better performance.
